# Power Automate Shopify API Connector and Export to Excel

Tags: excel, export-to-excel, power-automate, shopify-api

I am trying to read my Shopify Products and Export them to an Excel file. So I was able to create a custom Connector and Get products, however I have an issue of exporting them into an excel. I need the list of SKUs, however it runs few minutes and throws me an error that job has timed out. Can you please help with the Power Automate step for getting data from GetProduct custom app and write into the excel. I actually tried to extract titles, and it worked, however when I go to the lower level to get sku, the job times-out. [image: I]

Comment: Is the Shopify step the custom connector? If so, your question should target that part of your issue. Change the tag and provide more information about the connector and it’s configuration.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I edited the post. My issue is actually the 2nd part, which is writing data into the excel. I used GET endpoint to retrieve the list of all products, and it works for titles, but not for SKUs (https://shopify.dev/api/admin-rest/2022-04/resources/product)

Comment: Still too hard to help. If it’s a custom connector, show us the API definition. Give us technical information that allows us to try and recreate the issue so we can work on a fix for you.